# Help me solve this equation; I believe this is a transcendental equation

Tags: equation-solving

please can someone help me solve

```
 (x*L)+B*tan(x*L)=0,
```

solve for x when B=10;L=0.1. The equation looks innocent but I need to find 1st 5 roots of equ.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: `Plot` the function to see where the roots are, then use `FindRoot` to obtain the numerical  values.  The first is, of course, at `0`.  The second is at `28.6277`.

Answer (score 1):

If you constrain the domain of `x` you can use [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
B = 10;
L = 1/10;

eqn = (x*L) + B*Tan[x*L] == 0;

soln = NSolve[{eqn, 0 <= x <= 140}, x, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 10]

(*  {{x -> 0}, {x -> 28.62772588}, {x -> 57.60557933}, {x -> 
   87.08313831}, {x -> 117.0267808}}  *)
```

Verifying roots

```
And @@ (eqn /. soln)

(*  True  *)
```

Comment: You can also do `N[Reduce[{eqn,0<=x<=140},x]]`.